# A pendulum connected to a capacitor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, capacitance

A mathematical pendulum of length L whose rod is made of a conducting material
 moves so that its inferior end slides without friction on a metallic support in
 the shape of an arc of circle. The rod is rigid, of negligible mass, and it moves ina static magnetic field of induction $B$, orthogonal to the plane of the pendulum.

The bob of the pendulum is a point mass $m$. The metallic support and the fix
end of the pendulum are connected through an ideal capacitor of capacity $C$, the
electric circuit closing through the rod, as depicted in Fig. 2.16.
 Show that, neglecting the resistance and the inductance of the circuit, the period of oscillation of the pendulum is:

$$T = 2\pi\sqrt{\frac{L}{g}\left(1 + \frac{CB^2L^2}{4m}\right)}$$

[image]

I know that $2 \pi$ and square root $L/g$ is the period for a pendulum, and I tried to establish the relation between the capacitance and FEM because a current exist, and for that reason there's a change in the magnetic flux. I tried to see the units in the square root but I have not results.

The proposed problem is in Masud Chaichian "Electrodynamics An Intensive Course", chapter two, number 10.

Comment: Is $B$ directed upward or downward?

Comment: According to me, it points out of the screen, because the current is moving to the right side (in the capacitor´s direction)

Comment: Are you sure about the factor 4? I get a factor 2 (maybe I'm wrong though).

Comment: @Matteo, according to the book is 4.